# Short story about Humans using scams to overcome Alien Conquerors

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading this story on the internet a few years ago. It told the story of how humans defeated an alien invasion using scams. There were no characters, it was more like a documentary piece. One of the events that I remember had to do with humans using a phony telethon and I think the Nigerian scam to make money behind the aliens back. The story incorporated several famous internet scams in it.

Comment: Using the Nigerian scam on aliens is a new one! I hope you find the story. My +1!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found it. It is called *Planetary Defences* by S. R. Algernon, it can be found [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/504182a)

Turns out it wasn't a documentary, but a subordinate describing events to his superior.